# How can I find any bank accounts in my name?

Tags: banking, bank-account

30 years ago someone deposited $2000 on an account with both my and her name.  I kind of know the location surrounding the bank, but do not remember the name of the bank.  Is there any way I could find out how to locate the bank and if the money is still there?

Comment: Your State government offices (most likely the Treasurer's office) has a listing of abandoned bank accounts). Look to see if your name is listed there as an owner.

Comment: In what country/city/state?

Answer (score 1):

Google for "unclaimed funds"
You might need to do it for each state separately.